# Why does this infinite product over the primes converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

Consider the product
$$\prod_p\Big(1+\frac1{(p-1)^3}\Big)$$
over the primes. I can't easily see why this should converge. Something like $\prod_p\big(1+\frac 1{p-1}\big)$ doesn't converge, since (I believe) $\prod_{p\leqslant x}\big(1+\frac 1{p-1}\big)\sim\log\log x$.

I've rewritten the product as
$$\exp\bigg(\sum_{p}\sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(p-1)^{3n}}\bigg)$$
using the Taylor series for log, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Using the series with PrimeZetaP, it is easy to calculate that the product is equal to 2.300961544713237054556976148749396181260786597022167361376386118...

Comment: For the similar product (1 + 1/(p-1)^2) see OEIS https://oeis.org/A065485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the $n$th prime so$$p-1\ge n\implies1+(p-1)^{-3}\le\exp n^{-3},$$so your product $\le\exp\zeta(3)$.

Comment: How does the $\exp$ appear?

Comment: @cuqlajta Use $1+u\le\exp u$ with $u=n^{-3}$.

Comment: I guessed that that's why it's true, could you explain your intuition a bit please? I would have stopped at $1+(p-1)^{-3} \leq 1+n^{-3}$.

Comment: @ċuqlajta Which in turn $\le\exp n^{-3}$. You have to compare it to the exponential of something, so you can reduce the problem to whether some infinite series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Since,
for $x > 0$,
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
$\ln(1+x)
\lt x$
and
$\ln(1+x)
\gt \dfrac{x}{1+x}
\gt x-x^2
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_p\Big(1+\frac1{(p-1)^3}\Big)
&=e^{\sum_p \ln\Big(1+\frac1{(p-1)^3}\Big)}\\
&\lt e^{\sum_p \frac1{(p-1)^3}}\\
\end{array}
$

and since
$\sum_p \frac1{(p-1)^3}$
converges,
$e^{\sum_p \frac1{(p-1)^3}}
$ converges.

More generally,
if
$a_n > 0$ and
$\sum a_n$ converges then

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_n\Big(1+a_n\Big)
&=e^{\sum_n \ln(1+a_n)}\\
&\lt e^{\sum_n a_n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\prod_n\Big(1+a_n\Big)$
converges.